# Square API - Changing Charge Dates to CaptureTransaction Dates

Tags: square-connect

We're using the Square v2 API.

We're setting the `delay_capture` field to `true` in our `charge` API calls. When we then call the `CaptureTransaction` for that charge, the date of the transaction is the date the original `charge` call was sent.

Is there a way to set the date of the transaction to the date the `CaptureTransaction` call was sent rather than the original `charge` date?

I don't see any support for this in the documentation but I figured I would ask.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot change the recorded dates. I'd recommend using another database to store this additional data and just key on the `transaction id`.